How to render Markdownx content as HTML in a Django blog project?
I did all the installation of markdownx steps as stated.
I've installed the django-markdownx package using pip install django-markdownx.
I've added 'markdownx' to my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.
I've defined a MarkdownxField in my blog post model to store the Markdown content.
but my problem is I'm unsure about the correct template tag usage to render the Markdown content as HTML.
this is my models.py:
from django.db import models
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = MarkdownxField()

    def __str__(self):

this is my viwes.py:
from .models import Article


def post_list(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'articles': articles})

this is my admins.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin

admin.site.register(Article, MarkdownxModelAdmin)

this is my urls.py of project(not app):
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
    path('', include("blog.urls")),
]

in the admin it shows the preview correctly but I used many tags to convert the markdownx to html but I'm not successfull.
I used:
{% for article in articles %}
    <article>
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <div>{{ article.content|markdown|safe }}</div>
</article>
{% endfor %}

but I got TemplateSyntaxError.
I used:
{% for article in articles %}
    <article>
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <div>{{ article.content|markdownify }}</div>
</article>
{% endfor %}

I got TemplateSyntaxError.
Also I used:
{% for article in articles %}
    <article>
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <div>{{ article.formatted_markdown|safe|linebreaks }}</div>
</article>
{% endfor %}

again I got just the title and content or markdown field not showing at all.
I couldn't find any example in django-markdownx documentation, in the other websites they used with one of the above solutions that I tried but I'm not sucessful .

This is the best way to do so

By the looks of it, markdownx does its markdown rendering and HTML conversion via a form field widdget and javascript (see the markdownx docs). But you are not using a formfield - you are using the model field directly - so markdownx doesn't do anything to help you here.
Either you find some other way to turn the markdown into HTML (there are no built-in django tags or filters that do that), or you use forms in your templates so that markdownx can use its script.

So what you mean is that we must have a form for writing a blog and only through that we can enter the content of the blog so that the markdown is rendered. And we can't just enter the information through the admin panel and wait for it to be rendered. Did I understand correctly?

Only if, for some reason, you really need to use this markdownx library (because markdownx only works on form widgets). If you just want some markdown rendered as HTML, then you could use other libraries like https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/ and pass that HTML to your template (remember to mark it as safe).
